# QDox to obtain enum value names

Tags: java, qdox

Does QDox provide a way to get the names of the enum values defined by an enum? (I know it can be done using reflection, but I want to be able to get the JavaDoc as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it does suport Enums but it doesn't read the enum constants inside. Maybe extending `JavaDocBuilder` and doing a few more changes this can be added.